# i can't install kivy im not a developer i need asistance even chat gpt didn't help me

Tags: python, kivy

Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-67.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEFr0.png)

i tryied everything i know + CHAT GPT updating pip uninstaling python from my pc ... but no result same error after i enter pip install kivy
creating virtual environmnet etc same error
I use python 3.11

Comment: Chat GPT is not a serious programming resource

Comment: Problem slved tnx i m now using 3.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely getting this error because the current version of Kivy supports Python versions **3.7-3.10**. (From their [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/faq.html))

To properly install Kivy, you're going to need to drop down to a lower version of Python. Try reading [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) article if you need help with that.